# Team Foundation Server online using SQL Server Manager Studio 2014?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs

I'm using TFS online and it works great with Visual Studio 2013. I'm developing against SQL Server 2014 and I want to be able to push my SQL backups and SQL code up to it.

I've created a folder on my `C:` called `DB_Backups` and I save my SQL DB backups there (naturally).  In Visual Studio 2013 I've added a new folder to my project and then added (an existing item) my `dbbackup.bak`.  I was able to push that to TFS through my project and Visual Studio.  However, when I ran the SQL Server backup again, overwriting the previous backup, the change wasn't caught in Visual Studio.

How can I integrate my SQL stuff with TFS?

Comment: In SQL Server there is an option for *appending to* or *overwrinting* backup files, Are you looking for that ;).

Comment: It may be easier to do this through the windows shell extensions that come as part of TFS power tools https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f